# How to use sed/awk to extract text between two patterns when a specific string must exist in the text block

Tags: awk, sed

I have found several answers on how to sed/awk between two patterns but I need also to find only the specific text block that has a string inside!

Text example:

```
<requirement        id = "blabla.1"
                slogan = "Handling of blabla"
          work-package = "bla444.2"
          logical-node = "BLA-C"
                 level = "System"
>
Bla bla.
</requirement>
<requirement        id = "bla.2"
                slogan = "Reporting of blabla"
          work-package = "bla444.1"
          logical-node = "BLA-C"
                 level = "System"
>
Bla bla bla.
</requirement>
```

So the goal is to get only the text block between  &  which should have bla444.1 in the work-package! This should give me in the example only the last text block. Of course the file that i would like to sed have more requirements and several with the needed work-package, so not only the last text block that sed will find.

```
sed -e 's/<requirement\(.*\)<\/requirement/\1/' file
```

The above sed line will give all the text blocks (requirements).

One thing is that the text block has no fixed line count but all will have work-package!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
/^<requirement/{
  if(found && value){
    print value
  }
  found=value=""
}
{
  value=(value?value ORS:"")$0
}
/work-package.*bla444.1\"$/{
  found=1
}
END{
  if(found && value){
    print value
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                           ##Starting awk program from here.
/^<requirement/{                ##Checking condition if line starts from string <requirement then do following.
  if(found && value){           ##Checking condition if found and value is NOT NULL then do following.
    print value                 ##Printing value(which contains all blocks value, explained further code) here.
  }
  found=value=""                ##Nullifying variables found and value variables here.
}
{
  value=(value?value ORS:"")$0  ##Creating variable value whose value is keep concatenating its own value each time cursor comes here.
}
/work-package.*bla444.1\"$/{    ##Checking condition if a line has string work-package till bla444.1 then do following.
  found=1                       ##Making variable found and setting value to 1, kind of FLAG enabling stuff.
}
END{                            ##Starting END block of this awk code here.
  if(found && value){           ##Checking condition if found and value is NOT NULL then do following.
    print value                 ##Printing value variable here.
  }
}
'  Input_file                   ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: This does actually do the work! How can I change it to find work-package that have bla444 only since I have many from bla444, bla444.1...x?

Comment: OK, i figured it out: `awk '/^<requirement/{if(found && value){print value};found=value=""} {value=(value?value ORS:"")$0} /work-package.*bla444.*\"$/{found=1} END{if(found && value){print value}}' file`. This will give all the work-package(s) with bla444, bla444.1...x

Comment: @FotisK, Sorry I was away from system, cool Good to hear that you figured it out, cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/<requirement/{:a;N;/<\/requirement/!ba;/work-package = "bla444\.1"/p}' file
```

Filter lines between `<requirement` and `</requirement>` and if those lines contain the string `work-package = "bla444.1"` print the collection.

Or perhaps:

```
sed -ne '/<requirement/{' -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '/<\/requirement/!ba' -e '/work-package = "bla444\.1"/p' -e '}' file
```

Or:

```
cat <<\! | sed -nf - file
/<requirement/{
:a
N
/<\/requirement/!ba
/work-package = "bla444\.1"/p
}
!
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I assume due to sed version differences on different systems. `> sed -n '/<requirement/{:a;N;/<\/requirement/;/work-package = "bla444\.1"/p}' file` with error msg: `sed: -e expression #1, char 37: unknown command: `;'`

Comment: @FotisK perhaps your version of sed does not understand the command separator `;` in which case each command can be separated into `-e`  option, see edit. Or written into a file `commandFile` with each command on a separate line and called `sed -nf commandFile file`